# Android does not come NotificationCompat class

Tags: android, android-layout

i use eclips for developing android programming and use android 4.4 API but when wrote NotificationCompat.builder error come class not found My question is why dont come predefind class

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NotificationCompat cannot be resolved to a type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21055732/notificationcompat-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type)

Answer (score 0):

Have you added support library? If yes then you must be able to import appropriate classes.

If not then you can add support library as it doesn't come pre-added in eclipse projects.

You can use android studio as ide and gradle as build tool. project created by android studio already have support library added to it.

Comment: How to add support library

Comment: NotificationCompat.Builder notifBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);    when i wore this line error come plse create class

Comment: https://www.google.com.pk/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html&ved=0ahUKEwjCz5vR16fRAhUBthQKHd96BPYQFggtMAM&usg=AFQjCNEvQsDbxALAaJmHTaQ7ATSOfFcGZg

Comment: i Add Supported files but still error come   NotificationCompat.Builder =